# Custom Bootstrap dialog

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a custom bootstrap dialog where the action buttons on the footer should be aligned vertically on the right hand side. Here is what I have so far ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPfd/))
This gives:

[image]

What I want to achieve is something like:
[image]

**Problem**
How do I split a bootstrap dialog into two parts? One for the buttons on the right and the other for the content on the left?
It seems that using this does not do it

```
<div id="myModal1" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog large">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right no-padding" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row no-margin">
          <div class="col-xs-8">
             ... content here....
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 action-buttons">
             ... buttons here ....
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem may be that you're using Bootstrap 3.x markup, but your fiddle is including Bootstrap 2.x

Using Bootstrap 3, little custom CSS is needed...

```
.action-buttons {
    padding: 5% 0;
}
.list-unstyled {
    padding: 10% 0;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/LA8IWDd7KW

Answer (score 2):

Add custom classes:

```
<div class="col-xs-8 realign-right">
    ... content here....
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 action-buttons realign-left ">
    ... buttons here ....
</div>
```

Wrap your buttons, give them a custom class:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 realign-left">
    <div id="squeeze">
        <button class="btn customb" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary customb">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add custom CSS:

```
.realign-right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
}


.realign-left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}

 #squeeze {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 90px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 45px;
}

.customb {
  margin: 4px;
}
```

**[Your result should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkPem.png)**
 | **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPfd/2/)**

This is why I hate bootstrap. Every time I try to make something custom, I end up rewriting  the bootstrap CSS.